# What is used when we want to bring down and present data from an API, but don't require persistence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsarray

I use Core Data for most of my projects that require data persistence from launch to launch, but what if I just want to pull information down from an API such as Twitter's and present it to the user, *and I don't require it to be persistent from launch to launch*?

Is the typical solution here to simply use `NSMutableArray` and store all the objects therein, and create a class for what's stored in it, similar to Core Data's managed objects?

Comment: Answer updated with a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success using [Mantle](https://github.com/blog/1299-mantle-a-model-framework-for-objective-c).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an NSMutableArray of custom objects will work. An NSMutableArray of NSDictionary's is also a common solution, and works well for simple data sets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1

Assuming that you can request a JSON response from the server, the code to pull information from the server would look something like this.  The `jsonData` object produced by this code consists of nested NSArrays and NSDictionarys. The NSLog at the end will dump the data set returned by the server.

```
- (void)retrieveJSONdataFromServer:(NSString *)param1 
{
    NSError *error;

    NSString *str  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/sometopic/api/json?param1=%@", param1 ];
    NSURL    *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

    if ( !data )
    {
        NSLog( @"%@", error );
        return;
    }

    id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

    if ( !jsonData )
    {
        NSLog( @"%@", error );
        return;
    }

    // do something with the JSON data here

    // for this sample code, we just dump the data to the debug console
    NSLog( @"%@", jsonData );
}
```